# Apache vhost double slash on redirects

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, vhosts

I was trying to force the FQDN and HTTPS via Apache Vhost redirects in a Laravel application behind a reverse Proxy. My problem now is that the user sometimes gets redirected to a URL with double slash e.g. `https://exampledomain.xy//test` instead of `https://exampledomain.xy/test` and I'm not sure why.

Here is my apache vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

 <Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog /dev/stderr
 TransferLog /dev/stdout
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=::1
 RewriteRule (.*) https://exampledomain.xy/$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public"
 ServerName exampledomain.xy
</VirtualHost>
```

And my .htaccess file (default .htacces file that comes with Laravel)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay looks like I fixed the issue. I changed the following in my config:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://stk-support.ukl.uni-freiburg.de$1 [R=301,L]
```

The extra slash in the rewrite rule was causing the issue and I also added a HTTPS rewrite condition.